# PGFplotstable: Skip rows containing nan

Tags: pgfplotstable

Forgive me, but I have not been able to find an answer. I have some text-files organized like the one below, which I typeset into a table using pgfplotstable

```
\documentclass[border=1pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotstableread{
no A B C D
1  2 3 4 3
2  nan nan nan 4
3  2 3 4 5
4  2 3 4 6
5  2 3 4 7
6  nan nan nan 8
7  2 3 4 9
}\datatable

\begin{document}
\pgfplotstabletypeset[header=true,columns={no,A,B,C}]\datatable
\end{document}
```

Is there any way I can skip the rows containing nan without hardcoding the skip? I guess the answer lies in row predicate/.code={} somewhere, but I am getting nowhere.

Answer (score 0):

I feel stupid now. I managed to solve it after all.

```
    \documentclass[border=1pt]{standalone}
    \usepackage{pgfplotstable}
    \pgfplotstableread{
    no A B C D
    1  2 3 4 3
    2  nan nan nan 4
    3  2 3 4 5
    4  2 3 4 6
    5  2 3 4 7
    6  nan nan nan 8
    7  2 3 4 9
    }\datatable
    
    \begin{document}

\pgfplotstabletypeset[
col sep=tab,
header=true,
row predicate/.code={%
    \pgfplotstablegetelem{#1}{A}\of{\datatable}
    \pgfmathfloatparsenumber{\pgfplotsretval}
    \let\A=\pgfmathresult
    \pgfmathfloatgetflagstomacro\A\flags
    \ifnum\flags=3\relax\pgfplotstableuserowfalse
    \else\relax\fi}]{\datatable}
\end{document}
```

Does anyone know how I can define a command to skip the nan rows in the preamble?

I tried

```
\newcommand{skipnans}[3]{
row predicate/.code={%
    \pgfplotstablegetelem{#1}{#2}\of{#3}
    \pgfmathfloatparsenumber{\pgfplotsretval}
    \let\A=\pgfmathresult
    \pgfmathfloatgetflagstomacro\A\flags
    \ifnum\flags=3\relax\pgfplotstableuserowfalse
    \else\relax\fi}
```

Using `\skipnans{#1,A,\datatable}` gives an error of extra }'s

Comment: You can replace `\else\relax\fi` by just `\fi`.